# JSON string not loading data into local storage

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building an application that will load bus schedules into local storage, then based on a search term provides the stops on the bus schedule. It works by clicking the load button and sending the information to local storage. Then you search a route name, and the stops information will be displayed into results. When I run in a browser my data is not loading into local storage when I press load.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * A JSON string that holds data. There is no problem with the JSON string
 * @type {String}
  */

    var busSchd = '{"Routes": [{"routeName": "Milledge","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "Orbit","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "East West","stops":[{"Stop 1":"East Campus Deck","Stop 2":"Creswell Hall","Stop 3":"Hull St Deck","Stop 4":"Main Library","Stop 5":"Joe Frank Harris"}]}]}';

    
const load = () => {
    let data = JSON.parse(busSchd);
    console.log("a");
for (var i = 0; i < data.Routes.len;)
     {
         let route = data.Routes[i];
         let routeStr = route.routeName;
         localStorage.set(routeStr, JSON.stringify(route.stops));
      }

};

    const clicked = () => {
     
       var search = document.getElementById("search");
       var results = localStorage.getItem("search");

      if (results === null) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>There are no results for that route name.</b>";
      } else {
        var stops = results;
        var output = '';
        for (var key in stops[0]) {
          output = output + '<b>' + key + '</b> : ' + stops[0][key] + '<br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Load Route Data" id="load" onclick="load();">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="search"><input type="button" value="Find Route" id="submit" onclick="clicked();"><br>
  <br><br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your for loop is missing an increment.

Comment: what would that look like?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < data.Routes.len; i++)`

Comment: This still doesnt load the data into local storage

Comment: it is also `length` in `data.Routes.length` and not `len`

Comment: changing those two things should execute the `set`

Comment: its returning this error localStorage.set is not a function at load

Comment: use `setItem`, `getItem` and `removeItem`

Comment: how would i do that with this code?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few mistakes within your code which prevented you from saving to localStorage. Here are some pointers.

- Use `localStorage.setItem()` to save and `localStorage.getItem()` to retrieve data.
- There's no need for creating a localStorage item for each bus route. LocalStorage can handle quite some data, depending on the browser and user browser settings. See [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) for more info.
- I'd simplify your data structure. Why put stops data into an array and then into an object? I've simplified this in my example.
- When iterating over items use `for (var i = 0; i < data.Routes.length; i++) { // your code here }` another alternative is to user [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) when iterating over items within an array.

Here's how to load data and save it to localStorage and into the app.

```
let BusSchdDataFromLocalStorage = [];

const load = () => {
  // access localStorage and save the result in data 
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('routesInfo'));
  if (data === null) {
    // if no data is present, save InitialBusScheduleData to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('routesInfo', JSON.stringify(InitialBusScheduleData));
  }

  // Now that data is present in localStorage, read it.
  data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('routesInfo'));
  if (data.Routes.length > 0) {
    // if routes are present, save its data to a global var in our app
    BusSchdDataFromLocalStorage = data;
    statusEl.innerHTML = 'localStorage data present'
  } else {
    statusEl.innerHTML = 'localStorage data absent'
  }
};
```

Here's how the search part works.

```
const search = () => {
  const searchString = document.querySelector('#search').value;
  // data from localStorage is present in the variable below 
  const routes = BusSchdDataFromLocalStorage.Routes;

  // Filter route data based on the search input. 
  const busStopInfo = routes.reduce((stops, route) => {
    return (route.routeName.toLowerCase() === searchString.toLowerCase()) ? route.stops : stops;
  }, []);
  const stops = Object.keys(busStopInfo);
  // map over the stops and return the html structure with the stop number and the value
  const results = stops
    .map((stop) => '<div>' + stop + ' - ' + busStopInfo[stop] + '</div>')
    .join('');
  // add the html result to the result div.
  resultEl.innerHTML = results.length > 0 ? results : 'No route found with that name.';
};
```

If you'd like to see the code in action. [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/bk3pj610/195).